# How do I boot my MacBook Air running Lion in safe mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, safe-mode

I follow the instructions in http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455 to boot in Safe Mode, but it appears something different happens with Lion.  After holding the shift key when hearing the startup tone, the icons for the two accounts I have configured come up as usual.  If I hold the shift key after logging in, the screen stays grey and a status bar appears with a "sunburst" waiting animation.  (I don't know what the canonical name for that is.)  After the status bar fills, the waiting animation continues and then my MBA reboots.

How do I boot my MacBook Air (running Mac OS X 10.7.1) in Safe Mode?

Comment: If I boot my MacBook Air goes off after few second. I have tried to put on several times, it keeps going off after few second. Any help, I will appreciate

Answer (score 1):

In my 2011 MacBook Air running Lion, when I select `Restart...` from the `` menu, if I then hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key through the restart process, the boot process is distinctly different than a normal reboot. There is a progress bar across the bottom of the screen, and then I am deposited at the login window, despite normally automatically logging in. I suspect that a Safe Boot has indeed been performed. The difference between this an Safe Boot in previous versions is that no "Safe Mode" text appears on the login screen for me.

Comment: How can you tell that a Safe Boot has been performed?

Comment: Do you have more than one account or do you have automatic login disabled?  Or does it boot right into the Finder?

Comment: I have one account, with automatic login enabled. But when I booted with shift held down, I got the login window. I don't have any explicit indication that a safe boot occurred, but the progress bar and the login window don't usually show up, and they did in this case.